# Gong Wpf DragDrop : I can't get the mouse position using DragEventArgs in DragOver and Drop methods

Tags: c#, wpf, drag-and-drop

I am quite new to StackOverFlow and this is my first post so I'll try to give you as much details as I can

I have a problem with Gong DragDrop Solution : 
I have a simple listview in which I can, thanks to this library, reorder items by dragging and dropping, it works perfectly in that case !

Now my problem is this one : I want to get the mouse coordinates relative to a specific external UIElement ( a parent scrollviewer ) in the DragOver event provided

the listview drag and drop works as it should but in my case, I have two listviews side by side inside a scrollViewer block :

the one on the left can't be edited whatsoever
the one on the right is what the user will edit/reorder

I just want that parent scrollViewer to scroll when the user drags an item and goes near its boundaries.

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="parentScrollViewer">
<!-- 2 ListViews side by side, the one on the right is the one -->
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="5" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ListView
                    Grid.Row="1"
                    IsHitTestVisible="False"
                    BorderThickness="0"
                    FontWeight="Bold"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding ContentStructure}"
                    ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False"
                    >
                </ListView>
                <GridSplitter Grid.Column="1" Width="5" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />


                <!--listview where drag and drop is implemented !-->
                <ListView
                    x:Name="dragDropListView"
                    Grid.Row="1"
                    Grid.Column="2"
                    BorderThickness="1px,0,0,0"
                    AllowDrop="True"
                    dd:DragDrop.IsDragSource="True"
                    dd:DragDrop.IsDropTarget="True"
                    dd:DragDrop.DropHandler="{Binding}"
                    PreviewMouseWheel="FilesGrid_PreviewMouseWheel"
                    SelectionChanged="FilesGrid_SelectionChanged"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding SourceFiles, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                    ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False"
                    >
                </ListView>
            </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Implementing the IDropTarget interface in my view model, I get these methods which recieve as parameters the IDropInfo data. 
That's where I am stuck trying to find access to the event object itself ( DragEventArg ) in order to use it and call GetPosition.
I tried Mouse.GetPosition(parentScrollViewer) for example but it doesn't update coordinates as I move the mouse

```
        public void DragOver(IDropInfo dropInfo)
        {
            // e.GetPosition(parentScrollViewer) won't work here
            // dropInfo has a dropPosition property but it gives coordinates from the mouse relative
            // to the listView where the drag is happening not the parentScrollViewer
        }

        public void Drop(IDropInfo dropInfo)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
```

Please let me know if you have any hints or ideas
Thanks !

Comment: Does `listView.TranslatePoint(dropInfo.dropPosition, parentScrollViewer)` work?

Comment: I ended up literally adding changes to the IDropInfo interface to get access to the event object itself ! Not very practical I know..